# ExecuteReader error when selecting multiple columns "No data exists for row/column"

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I am trying to run a simple query that returns three columns but am running into an error stating that the data does not exist though I am quite certain it does.

This is the section of code in question.

```
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT school.id, school.city, school.state 
                           FROM school,city
                           WHERE school.name = '" & SchoolLb.SelectedItem & "'
                           AND city.name = '" & CityLb.SelectedItem & "';"

        'MessageBox.Show(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        profileSchool = myReader(0)
        profileCity = myReader(1)
        profileState = myReader(2)
```

The School list box is populated with schools located in the city that is currently selected in the city list box, so they match up. When I remove the comment tag from `MessageBox.Show(cmd.ExecuteScalar)` the `ExecuteScalar` runs and returns a message showing the ID of the correct record. However when using `cmd.ExecuteReader` I get the error mentioned above.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the reader and then advance it to the next record by using [`reader.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx):

```
Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    reader.Read()
    profileSchool = reader(0)
    profileCity = reader(1)
    profileState = reader(2)
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I have a ways to go with vb.net and databases!